# Who was Haman's mother?

Tags: names, women, historical-figures, purim, haman

Is there any mention of Haman's mother in rabbinic literature (Gemara, Midrash, etc.)?

If she was discussed in the Gemara or other sources, what was her name?

Comment: This question could be more compelling if you would [edit] in why you think that Haman's mother's name woudl have been mentioned somewhere, and why you want to know. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/306/if-i-know-the-answer-to-a-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Her name was אמתלאי בת עורבתי.

> ואמר רב חנן בר רבא אמר רב אמיה דאברהם אמתלאי בת כרנבו **אמיה דהמן
>   אמתלאי בת עורבתי** וסימניך טמא טמא טהור טהור

[Bava Basra 91a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=91&format=pdf)

See also [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47478/5323) to [What was Avraham Avinu's mother's name?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47477/5323)

Comment: side idea http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/why-isnt-shimsons-mother-named/17618#17618

Comment: You can't answer your own question.

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton I'd [beg to differ](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Based off gematria from the difference of their names (כרנבו = 278 ,and עורבתי = 688 ) the diffrence between them (688- 278 = 410) is bitachon in HaShem,when things go bad for Haman he turns to his evil family,but Avraham and his children turn to HaShem in times of trouble ,thats how they deafeat Haman,we see this from the passuk in tehillim 56:4 :יוֹם אִירָא אֲנִי אֵלֶיךָ אֶבְטָח and this passuk equals 410